# Programmatically paint an illuminated section of a speedometer

Tags: image, qt, qml, paint

I am trying to make a gauge in Qt Quick that has sections that "light up" from 0 to the needle's position.

One way I can think of doing this is by having an image of the segment and painting it and rotating it many times from code. However, I don't know how this can be done in QML.

It doesn't have to be QML and it doesn't have to be Qt Quick; it could be anything as long as I can use it with Qt and within Qt creator and preferably works accross platforms.

**Edit**: Made rough sketch but StackOverflow requires me to have 10 reputation to post them, so I am placing links.

[No segments illuminated](http://lj9.mexinetica.com/fotogen/2014_SO/gauge255_bg_0.png)    ----------------------------   [Some segments illuminated](http://lj9.mexinetica.com/fotogen/2014_SO/gauge255_bg_1.png)
[image] - [image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot/GIF/video of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It can be easy done with Image and one of Animations I guess. In pure QML of cource

Comment: @Mitch: Added links to images.

Comment: @folibis: I'll check out the "Animations" that you suggest, thanks

Comment: @folibis I want the segments to stay illuminated, so I don't think your suggestion works for me (or I haven't understood how)

Comment: I edited the question to give it a more descriptive title; I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily use a `Canvas` element to draw an arc stroke with control over its start and end position. Just compose that below the scale of the gauge.

Here is an example how to do that using a value from 0 to 1 to select how "full" the gauge is.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        rotation: -90

        onPaint: {
            var c = getContext('2d')
            c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
            c.beginPath()
            c.lineWidth = 30
            c.strokeStyle = "red"
            c.arc(250, 250, 250 - 15, 0, Math.PI * 2 * circ.value)
            c.stroke()
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id: circ
        minimumValue: 0
        maximumValue: 1
        value: maximumValue / 2
        onValueChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
    }
}
```

As requested by Mitch, I explain - the canvas is rotated at 90 CCW degree because of the way Qt draws arcs - they do not start at "12 o'clock" but at 3. You can remove the rotation of the canvas just in case you might want to draw extra stuff, cuz you wouldn't want to make all your drawing offset at 90 degree just to sit right with the rotated canvas, all you need to do to get rid of the rotation is draw the arc in range `-Math.PI * 0.5` to `Math.PI * 1.5` to account for the art starting at 3 o'clock.

Comment: +1 for Canvas. :) This is almost exactly how I would have done it, except for the rotation trick; this will cause undesired rotation if certain things are drawn (like text, just as an example). You could mention why you rotate here, so that people know why it's there and the side effect I just mentioned.

Comment: This solution though not exact, is very good. 

Additionally, it gave me the idea to substitute the arc drawing inside the Canvas' onPaint for repeatedly drawing the rotated image, in case I absolutely needed to.